# Xcode: how to reset. No longer able to create outlet for newly added control in XIB

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have several XIBs following this pattern: a View Controller subclass containing a View subclass. I put my controls on that view.

Just now, I tried to add a new control to the view. I can do this, but I'm unable to connect the new control to an outlet. The assistant editor won't display the view subclass header either, though it will for a short while if I restart Xcode. Some other XIBs I have don't have the view controller object but instead have File's Owner set to a view controller subclass. They show the same problem.

Here is the Objects bar in IB:

[image]

"Matrix Editor View Controller" is a UIViewController subclass. This shows up fine in the Assistant Editor's "Counterparts" menu and I can drag from UIControls to it to create outlets & actions.

"Popup Cell View" is a UIView subclass. This is where the majority of my outlets and actions live. Previously this would show up in the Assistant Editor "Counterparts" menu and I could drag between it and my controls and the code quite happily. Now, whenever I add a new control in to this view, I can't drag from the Popup Cell View object to the new control, nor can I drag from the new control to the Assistant Editor window if it's showing the Popup Cell View header.

I recently had to upgrade to Lion (and hence Xcode 4.2.1 build 4D502); the last time I added controls to my XIBs was under Snow Leopard with the latest Xcode on that OS.

I believe that Xcode's caches or some internal state are out of whack. I have tried:

- Restarting Xcode
- A clean
- Removing and re-adding the view subclass from the project
- Deleting the DerivedData folder's contents from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode

And various combinations thereof. What else can I do to force Xcode to re-scan everything and allow me to connect up my controls to outlets?

Edit: I have noticed that I can create outlets in the View Controller for my new controls; I'm just not able to do this on the View subclass itself which is where I want them. I already have many on there. Could my new version of Xcode really be telling me that I'm not allowed to do this? Surely not. The Assistant Editor's Automatic mode changes every minute or so between two counterparts (the VC .h and .m) and four (the VC .h/.m and the View .h/.m).

Edit: I *was* able to connect an outlet, but only via this convoluted method:

1. Force the assistant editor to open my View subclass
2. Manually typing in an outlet for my new control
3. Dragging from the outlet in the assistant editor to the control itself

So something is very clearly broken. How can I fix it?

Very frustrating!

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by " The assistant editor won't display the view subclass header "? Do you mean you can't see the code for an entire file? Since I don't quite understand what you mean, which file are you referring to?

Comment: @Jim The assistant editor shows the View Controller .h & .m in the Counterparts menu. Sometimes it also shows the View .h & .m, but only for a few minutes. My outlets are mostly in the View. This all worked fine in Xc on Snow Leopard; it's code I've been working on for a while which hasn't changed since I had to upgrade. Appreciate the time by the way.

Comment: @Jim updated with a picture; worth 1K words apparently.

Comment: This has me stumped for the moment. The assistant editor should be no different from any other editor in regards to showing a text file. I can normally edit just about any text file in these editors. The fact that it is for a subclass of a view (which I think is your meaning) shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Jim I can bring up the View in the assistant editor *manually*, but even if I do that, I can't drag from new controls to the code to create new outlets and actions. The fact that the Assistant Editor's Counterparts window doesn't show the View as available is a symptom, not a cause. Thanks for making me check a few things though, much appreciated.

Comment: Good luck. I need my computer to look at this further, but I have to get to work. Thank for the up tic!

Answer (score 2):

When I have this problem, it is usually due to a mismatch in the class type somewhere. Verify that the class name of the object in you xib matched the class name in the interface and the implemetation files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newb - I recognize this is a kludge, but hope this helps somebody.  Sounds kinda sorta like the problem described above.

Suddenly, xcode refused to "insert new action outlets" into my AppDelegate.m (using control+drag, from a newly added xib element, into the class @implementation).  Also, Xcode does not display that little-dark-circle next to each IBAction method in the .m file, like it used to.

Xcode allows drag of the blue-line from the 'source xib element' -- but would not show the "Insert Outlet or Action" & blue-circle-line with destination-highlight at the 'target line of insertion', in the .m file.

However, I *can* insert new outlet into my AppDelegate.h, using that above-described blue-line drag-method.  That file is adorned with the cute little-black-circles, properly.

The kludge-around I came to was this

1. add 'bogus @implementation code' to the AppDelegate.h, as per:

   #if 1

   @implementation AppDelegate

   @end

   #endif
2. control+drag from the new xib element into/inside that #if 1 @implementation region in the .h

viola!  xcode now displays the desired "Insert Action" & blue-circle-line target at the position for insertion.  I can assign the method name and express whatever semantics I wish.  Xcode source-editor shows a cute little-dark-circle to the left of the 'autogenerated' -(IBAction) line.  For example, I added imanewxibobject as per:

```
#if 1

@implementation AppDelegate


- (IBAction)imanewxibobject:(id)sender {

    printf("%s: hi there!\n",\_\_FUNCTION\_\_);
}

@end

#endif
```

(1+2)=3.  Copy & paste that -(IBAction)imanewxibobject:... function into my actual AppDelegate.m (where it really belongs).

(2+2)=4.  Turn that #if 1 (in the AppDelegate.h) to #if 0

(3+2)=5.  recompile.  Kablammo, the new UI element is alive with semantics!

I tried all: cleaning the project, deleting the files from the project, etc.

I peered into that .xib file and found it contained lots of what appears to be cross-referenced identifier indices, kinda what you may expect to see, in a file of this sort.

So I still don't have those little-dark-circles beside my -(IBAction)s -- but at least the code compiles, and I see the correct method-label string, for the Xcode Utilities->"Show Connections Inspector", with respect to the new UI element.

Anybody know how I can restore those cute little-dark-circles beside my "-(IBAction)"s?  I find them very cute, and wish to have them back.  I don't see any "Display cute-little-dark-circles" menu options.  Bummer.  Maybe in the next Xcode?